# Using Java script to change part of a form

Tags: javascript, forms, simplecart

Is there a way to change the content of a form with Javascript?

I have a  series of paypal buttons, but want the user to be able to shop in CAD or USD.

The form looks something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<input name="amount" value="6.99" type="hidden" />
<input name="currency_code" value="CAD" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

I need to change the 
    value="CAD'
to
    value="USD"

Is there any way I could have a  button or some sort of 'toggle' on the site  whereby users can change the currency? It should happen to each product.

I had someone implement simple cart, but they are no longer available

is there a better way to do this?( I though this might be simplest)
But perhaps it should be done during checkout somehow? I presume this would be more complicated.

thanks in advance and hope I have been clear! let me know if you need more information.

my site is www.bodesi.com (if that helps)

Comment: Don't submit the prices in the form data. That just lets people change them.

Comment: @Quentin Upvote a thousand times. **NEVER** trust any input the user sends, even if it's in a "hidden" field.

Comment: But this is how paypal buttons work.

Comment: It is a very simple shopping cart. does this mean it cannot be done?

Comment: It's more a case of the what happens on the sellers end. For example, if it's an automated delivery system - then you are going to need to make sure every payment was not altered, obviously. However, if you're just implementing a simple cart for a small business and they are manually handling the orders, then this is a non-issue as they will be aware of any tampering immediately upon receiving the order.